# Why do I sometimes get a speed boost when leaving the spawn area?

Tags: overwatch

Sometimes when I leave the spawn area, I am moving much faster than usual. The speed seems to vary, as does how long it lasts. What is causing this?

Comment: Odds are, you had a Lucio on your team. He has a passive speed boost that can be amplified to further increase your speed.

Comment: Lucio would probably be why.

Comment: Ah, okay, that would make sense. That would also explain why the length of time varies. I'm probably getting out of range.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[**Lúcio**](https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/heroes/lucio/) was nearby.

One of his skills, **Crossfade** allows for nearby team members to move faster than usual.

> Lúcio continuously energizes himself—and nearby teammates—with music. He can switch between two songs: **one amplifies movement speed**, while the other regenerates health.

Emphasis mine.

As for why the speed increase varies, it's because of another one of his skills, **Amp It Up**, which boosts the effect of his **Crossfade** songs.

> Lúcio increases the volume on his speakers, boosting the effects of his songs.